# Cannot install unsigned APK file on my phone

Tags: installation, apk

I developed an app in Eclipse, and emailed to me the `.apk` file. It correctly downloads to my phone, then I go in `Downloads` and tap it. I choose "Install" and I'm getting `App not installed` message.

What's the problem?

I have a Nexus 4 phone, and "Unknown sources" option is selected. I can successfully install the app through Eclipse. The `.apk` file was exported in Eclipse from `Android tools -> Export unsigned application package`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `apk` file is also generated in the `bin` folder of the project after running the app at least once.

I've copied the `apk` file from the `bin` folder and installed it successfully on three different phones without any problem both copying directly on phone memory or sending it via email.

Answer (score 6):

Android does not allow installing **unsigned** applications.
You will need to sign you APK (with a debug or release key). Don't use `Android tools->Export unsigned application package`, but rather the regular command to export an Android APK.

The different options available to sign you app are well described here:
http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Answer (score 1):

Do you already have the application installed on your phone (installed via Eclipse)? If so I expect the exported apk is signed with a different key to the version already on your phone. Android will not allow you to 'update' an app if the signing key is different.

Un-install the app and try installing the apk again. If it still fails it may be that the exported app is corrupt in some way.

Comment: Yes, I already have the app installed. However, the exported app was unsigned. I tried to uninstall it, and install it again from .apk. It doesn't work. I've tried to install it also on a Galaxy S3 phone of a friend and I've got the same message. How can it be corrupted if I exported it using Eclipse, and launched from Eclipse it works? However I exported it again to be sure and doesn't work...:(

Comment: @blackwolf There are no unsigned apps in Android. If you haven't signed the app with a release key, it's signed with a "debug key", specific to the machine it was built on.

Comment: @DanHulme I think you are wrong. `Android tools->Export unsigned application package` does exactly what it says: create an unsigned APK. This is the reason it cannot be installed on a device: it's not even signed with the debug key.

Comment: @Sebastien I see what you're getting at. Yes, that seems the most likely explanation.